# Can't activate any virtual env

Tags: python, shell, virtualenv, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

When I trying to activate virtual environment using venv, pipenv and conda I always getting this error:

```
 venv/bin/activate:41: parse error near `deactivate'
```

There's content of activate file:
[Activate](https://gist.github.com/AlfredMulder/617550f339b6fccfb81ccd816a40c1d0)

Comment: please paste the content of your venv/bin/activate file on here. that is a bash script file. they would be a typo or syntax error on that file

Comment: What is your shell? `echo $SHELL`

Comment: I using oh-my-zsh shell.

Answer (score 0):

I had exacly same issue. It was conflicting alias in my case.
I had `alias fi="flatpak install --user"` in my ~/.zshrc.
When I commented that, command worked like this:

```
$ fi
zsh: parse error near `fi'
```

and `source venv/bin/activate` worked correctly